# What does 1.0 It current mean?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

A [datasheet](http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ACI4000/ACI4000PE5.pdf) of Li-Ion battery states "The current should be maintained at 1.0 It or less". What kind of unit is It?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datasheet has a 'Glossary of Terminology' which includes the definition of lt.

> Represents "Current" and is defined as follows It(A)= Rated Capacity (Ah) / 1(h).

As such, it appears to be the same as C rating ( i.e. 0.7lt charge current is 0.7C charge rate - after one hour, charge will be 0.7 times capacity in amp hours)

(the pdf seems to use lowercase L lt and uppercase i It inconsistently)

Comment: In other words, don't try to charge it fully in less than an hour,